# Centering a Text Link for Responsive Layout

Tags: css, wordpress, text, responsive-design, centering

I'm going nuts trying to figure out how to center the purple text link "buttons" on this page:

http://bit.ly/TrfmXk

I've tried all the usual tricks: margin: 0 auto, etc. but with the design being responsive and it only being contained in a

, I'm at a loss. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Apply this CSS to those links, for a start.

```
display: block;
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto !important;
```

Had to put !important on the margin, probably to override another rule somewhere else. You can change that width to whatever you'd like, as well.